# Dimension of certain matrix subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, matrix-rank, trace

Let $V:= \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $X \in V$ be given and
$$
U_X := \lbrace A \in V: \mathrm{trace}(AX) = 0 \rbrace
$$
a subspace. I want to find the dimension of $U_X$.

If $X = 0$, then clearly $U_X = V$ and therefore the dimension is $n^2$. If not, then I can choose $\tilde{A} \in V$ s.t. $\mathrm{trace}(\tilde{A}X) \neq 0$ and thus $A \mapsto \mathrm{trace}(AX)$ is a linear operator of rank 1. Consequently, $\dim U_X = n^2 - 1$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

Is this (short outline) correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: This looks good... Moreover, you're keeping your readers awake by using $A$ instead of the usual $X$ to denote the variable of the map $A \mapsto AX$!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Well, $X$ is already taken in this context